# Vim: remap key to toggle line numbering

Tags: vim, key-bindings, remap

I added:

```
set number
nnoremap <F2> :set nonumber!
```

to my vimrc file.  Basically what it's supposed to do is let me press <kbd>F2</kbd> to toggle line numbering but it's not working.  What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In your `.vimrc`, add this:

```
set number
nnoremap <F2> :set nonumber!<CR>
```

Then pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> will toggle line numbering.

Comment: This works perfectly for me, but just curious how would `nonumber!` implement the toggle function?

Comment: With latest vim, add `:set nonumber! norelativenumber!` if you use both number and relative number.

Answer (score 25):

This is what I use (with a different key binding):

```
nmap <f2> :set number! number?<cr>
```

The "number!" toggles the setting and "number?" reports the state.

Comment: This should be flagged as right anwser because more complete! This is the `lua` version for Neovim `vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<C-s>", ":set scrollbind! scrollbind?<CR>", { noremap = true, silent = true })`

Answer (score 8):

```
nmap <silent> <F11> :exec &nu==&rnu? "se nu!" : "se rnu!"<CR>
```

In new vim you can set both relative number and number at once, this way:

```
set nu rnu
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, is great for any kind of toggle, not just number toggling.

Comment: the new one way

`nmap <silent> <F11> :exec &nu==&rnu? "se nu!" : "se rnu!"<CR>`

Answer (score 5):

This is one method:

```
map <silent> <F2> :if &number <Bar>
    \set nonumber <Bar>
        \else <Bar>
    \set number <Bar>
        \endif<cr>
```

(this one is nice 'cause I usually put foldcolumn in there as well)

This is another:

```
map <silent> <F2> :set invnumber<cr>
```

(direct method)

Comment: I've just used the second method you shared with us. It's the one i prefer, thank you :)

Comment: The second method is far more correct and easy than anything else here (so far).  It should have been a separate *and accepted* answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use this to toggle between relativenumber ( with current absolute line number) and no line numbering

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>l :set relativenumber! <bar> set nu!<CR>
```