# VIM :set list! as a toggle in .vimrc

Tags: vim

Is there any way in my .vimrc file to use the command `set list!` with a keybind like <kbd>F3</kbd> so it functions like this paste toggle `set pastetoggle=<F2>`.

Comment: See this question for possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773722/how-can-i-toggle-smartcase-in-vim?rq=1

Comment: `pastetoggle` is only an option because of its special use case.  It defines a mapping that exists when all mappings are disabled.  See the answer above for how to create a map to toggle normal options.

Comment: I always just do `:se list!` and then `@:` to toggle

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can put this in your `.vimrc` file:

```
" F3: Toggle list (display unprintable characters).
nnoremap <F3> :set list!<CR>
```

Comment: It works great as long as I'm not in insert mode but in insert mode it prints "<F3>" any way to fix that. If not, as it is is still a huge help to me, thanks :)

Comment: Although toggling the `'list'` setting is pretty obvious if you where toggling some other setting say, `'spell'` it might be much less so. You can improve upon this mapping by just adding `list?` to the `set` command. This will print out the current value of the `'list'` setting. So in full it would be `nnoremap <f3> :set list! list?<cr>`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the mapping for normal mode, visual+select mode, and operator-pending mode (e.g. after typing <kbd>d</kbd>):

```
noremap <F3> :set list!<CR>
```

The nice thing about the function keys (vs. `<Leader>`) is that they can also be mapped in insert mode:

```
inoremap <F3> <C-o>:set list!<CR>
```

To be complete, you could also create a map for command-line mode:

```
cnoremap <F3> <C-c>:set list!<CR>
```

Read more about the various mapping modes at `:help map-modes`

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer about how to toggle `set number` in vim, https://stackoverflow.com/a/762633/1086911

So can try the same way by putting following line into your `vimrc` file

```
map <F3> :set list! list? <CR>
```